# Finding items from a python listed dictonary according to the length of maximum values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

Suppose I am having a dictionary like :

```
dicl = {'amazon': [668, 667, 879], 'flipkart': [678], 'hey': [89,79]}
```

I want to print the dictionary items based on the descending order of the items length.

The output I want :

```
{'amazon' : 3, 'hey' : 2, 'flipkart' : 1}
```

But I am getting results in sorted order of items whereas I want to display items on the basis of descending order of items?

What I have tried:

```
cov_m = {k : len(v) for k, v in sorted(dicl.items())}
```

Current Output:

```
{'amazon' : 3, 'flipkart' : 1, 'hey' : 2}
```

Comment: that is not a valid dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass a key `lambda` function as an argument to the `sorted` function to specify your sorting criteria:

```
dicl = {'amazon': [668, 667, 879], 'flipkart' : [678], 'hey' : [89,79]}

cov_m = {k : len(v) for k, v in sorted(dicl.items(), key = lambda i : -len(i[1]))}

print(cov_m)
```

Output:

```
{'amazon': 3, 'hey': 2, 'flipkart': 1}
```

Here, `len(i[1])` is the length of the value, and I'm sorting by `-len(i[1])` (negative length) because you want them in descending order, in case of more advanced sorting criteria, you should use `, reverse = True)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Geek. Suppose I need to preserve the item details like this : `{'amazon': ([668, 667, 879], 3), 'hey': ([89, 79], 2), 'flipkart': ([678], 1)}`. How to do this I have tried something like this but not getting the desired result. I have tried is `{k[0]: (len(v)) for k, v in sorted(dicl.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)}`

Comment: @MishraS Just change `k : len(v)` to `k : (v, len(v))` in the definition of `cov_m`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted` with custom key.

**Ex:**

```
dicl = {'amazon': [668, 667, 879], 'flipkart': [678], 'hey' : [89,79]}
print({k: len(v) for k, v in sorted(dicl.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)})
```

**Output:**

```
{'amazon': 3, 'hey': 2, 'flipkart': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would transform the data into a sorted list:

```
data = {'amazon': [668, 667, 879], 'flipkart': [678], 'hey': [89,79]}
sorted_data = sorted([{'name':k, 'val':len(v)} for k,v in data.items()],
                     key=lambda x: x['val'],
                     reverse=True)

print(sorted_data)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'name': 'amazon', 'val': 3}, {'name': 'hey', 'val': 2}, {'name': 'flipkart', 'val': 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Both suggested answers call `len()` twice on every item. Why not call it only once? (not for performance but for coolness)

**Code**

```
dicl = {'amazon': [668, 667, 879], 'flipkart': [678], 'hey' : [89,79]}

length_dict = {k: len(v) for k, v in dicl.items()} 

# Sort on length-values in dict, use inverse of length as @MrGeek suggests
sorted_on_values = sorted(
    length_dict.items(),
    key=lambda d: -d[1]
)
sorted_dict = dict(sorted_on_values)
```

**output**

```
{'amazon': 3, 'hey': 2, 'flipkart': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
 dicl = {'amazon': [668, 667, 879], 'flipkart': [678], 'hey' : [89,79]}

 cov_m = {k : len(v) for k,v in sorted(dicl.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])}
```

Output

```
{'amazon': 3, 'hey': 2, 'flipkart': 1}
```

Comment: an OrderedDict is only needed when you want to preserve the order as new key-value pairs are added. In OP's scenario, he already has a populated dictionary that he wants to sort.

Comment: @SamLegesse you are right, that's why  i gave both the solutions.If he wants to preserve dict then can use OrderedDict.

Comment: or if you're using python 2